# Python "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" - I'm not using "str" in code

Tags: python

I am getting a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in the following piece of code on the line beginning with "exists":

```
@app.route('/passwordLoginForm1', methods=['GET','POST'])
def passwordLoginForm1():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    exists = db.get_passdetails(username,password)

    if exists == 'true':
            return render_template('pin.html') 
    else:
            return render_template('passwordsLogin2.html')
```

This is the get_passdetails for reference:

```
def get_passdetails(username,password):
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT *  FROM Password WHERE username = %s AND password = %s" (username, password))
    details = cur.fetchone()
    if details:
        return 'true'
    else:   
        return 'false
```

Relatively new to Python so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Most likely `db.get_passdetails` is a string (although the name suggests a function). Python will generate this error if you try to use a string value variable like you would a function (i.e. followed by parentheses with or without parameters). Perhaps `get_passdetails` is a poorly named property of `db`?

Comment: What db library is this? I don't think that is how you format the query, missing %?

Comment: You're missing a comma after `"SELECT * FROM .... AND password = %s"`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the error is actually in this expression:

```
"SELECT *  FROM Password WHERE username = %s AND password = %s" (username, password)
```

Since there's no operator between the string and the `(...)`, it's being interpreted as a function call on a string (which naturally produces an error since a string isn't a function).  You meant to put a `%` in between.

Answer (score 3):

use ? instead of %s and don't forget to add comma,

```py
cur.execute("SELECT *  FROM Password WHERE username = ? AND password = ?" ,(username, password))
```

Comment: This is a good tip as it prevents sql injection. The formatting might depend on the library and sql dialect.

Comment: @IamFr0ssT yes it is more secure than just adding some formatted string